# Ubuntu Recommendation

Tags: 16.04

I am a little bit confused which Ubuntu to install on my pc. I used 16.04 before and I was satisfied, but now I checked the Ubuntu page and there were 2 versions available there, Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and Ubuntu 17.10.1? Which one do you guys suggest?

Comment: "Which one do you guys suggest?" The one you want to use ;) and the difference between the 2 is almost zero in regards to hardware. 16.04.3 is the 3rd version of 16.04. 16.04.2 is 17.04, 17.10 = 16.04.3. Only the software has newer versions.

Comment: The first choice should be the LTS version (16.04), particularly in a computer, where you know already that it works. If you were running a version that you installed from an early iso file, '16.04' or '16.04.1', you should stick with that version, which stays with the xenial kernel (4.4), otherwise install from the 16.04.3 iso file. If you intend to install Ubuntu into a new computer, 17.10.1 might be a good choice because it comes with new hardware drivers. See also this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04.* is the most recent Long Term Support version.  This is the most stable, least subject to change over its lifetime, and is supported for five years from release (until April 2021).  Ubuntu 17.10.* is not LTS, and its support will end in July 2018, with the expectation that you'll replace it with 18.04.

If you like the idea of having the absolute latest stable version, install 17.10.1 and be prepared to replace it in a couple months.  If you like the idea of having the same version for a prolonged period (and not having to re-learn your way around every few months), install 16.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions guys. I am going for the LTS version :D